# UseRef is not selecting the DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I actually want to add functionality where the user click on the Edit button of the Card component then the modal of bootstrap should be displayed on the onclick. Therefore i used bootstrap Modal feature where there i hide the Bootstrap button with d-none class and pass ref to the Modal component and assign the ref to the button in the modal componet but still when i does console log then there is nothing.

App.js

```
 function App() {

  const [li,Setli]=useState([]);
  const btn=useRef('');
  useEffect(()=>{
    Setli(li=>[...li,<Card />]);
    
  },[])

  function Add(){
    Setli(li=>[...li,<Model btn={btn}/>])
    console.log(btn.current);
   
  }
  return (
  <>
  <CardContext.Provider value={Add}>

  {li.map((t,i)=>(
    <div key={i}>{t}</div>
  ))}
  </CardContext.Provider>
  </>
  );
}
```

Modal.js

```
import React from "react";

const Model= React.forwardRef((props,btn)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        ref={btn}
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
      >
        Launch static backdrop modal
      </button>

      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="staticBackdrop"
        data-bs-backdrop="static"
        data-bs-keyboard="false"
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">
                Modal title
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">...</div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                Understood
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})

export default Model;
```

Comment: if you log the ref before the component is rendered, you'll get null

Comment: but i am doing it after the useState

Comment: this has nothing to do with useState, you are logging it before the Modal is being rendered, and so there is nothing for the ref to be attached to

Comment: so what should i do I have to add btn.current.click() just after the  Setli(li=>[...li,<Model btn={btn}/>]) and it is giving error